# Re-render Component on DB Upload

Tags: react-native

Quite new to React Native, I'm working with a small photo/text upload app, I'm having problems with automatically refreshing the component that displays the posts, after they have been uploaded.

The issue is that the uploader is within another component that is within a modal stack and I can't directly change state nor can I pass a component from parent to child as props (as the uploader component is not a child).

As I understand it, I would usually have two options:

1. Pass a function from parent to child as props in order to change the state of the display component to trigger its refresh. I have tried this and as there is no parent-child relationship, it does not work.
2. Implement redux throughout the app, again to change the (global) state and trigger the display component to refresh. I have begun to do this but it seems completely over the top for something that should relatively simple.

Is there any other options? And if not, is there a good guide around using redux to trigger component refresh?

Code:

The component that displays the db items. Currently it will only display fully with a manual update.

```
//This is the display component.
class VaultScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            itemsFormatted: [],
            photo_id: null,
            itemSelected: '',
            searchQuery: '',
            numberOfUploads: 0
         };
      this.refreshFlatListItem = this.refreshFlatListItem.bind(this)
  }

  //This function is called in the upload component so we change the state and reload the display. It is currently not being called/not working.
  refreshFlatListItem = () => {
      console.log('test')
      this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
              numberOfUploads: prevState.numberOfUploads +1
          };
      });
  }
```

The modal component that is responsible for the upload.

```
//This class is the component in the modal, used for uploading text.
class AddTextModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            textCaption: null,
        };
    this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
    }

    //the upload function is declares so we can access the refreshFlatListItem function in the display
    upload() {
        this.props.refreshFlatListItem;
    }

    //onSubmit is called when the user hits the 'submit' button. It takes the textInput and logs it to the console.
    //If it isn't null it adds it to the SQLite DB, calls the upload function (that changes the state of the display to trigger reload)
    //then resets the textInput state and navigates to the vault
    onSubmit = ()  => {
        const { textCaption } = this.state;
        console.log(textCaption)

        if (textCaption != null) {
                this.add(textCaption);
                this.upload
                this.setState({ textCaption: null });
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Vault')
            } else {
        return null
        }
    }

    //add is called in the upload and adds our textInput into the DB. It does not load into display automatically.
    add(text) {
      db.transaction(
        tx => {
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO items (value, caption, type) values (?, ?, ?)', [null, text, 'thought']);
        },
        null,
      );
    }
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
              return (
                      <NavigationContainer>
                        <Stack.Navigator
                          initialRouteName="Home"
                          mode='modal'
                          screenOptions={{
                              cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
                              cardOverlayEnabled: true
                          }}
                        >
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="Vault"
                            component={Main}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                          />
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="Modal"
                            component={Modal}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                          />
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
              );
            }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you tried in your first option? If the uploader component is not the child, how and where is it actually invoked?

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question to include the code of what I tried for the first option. The uploader component is invoked in a component within a modal in a different navigator stack. Basically it's a separate entity from the display. If unclear let me know

Comment: refreshFlatListItem goes to the upload component as props ? Also did you forget to invoke the function, as the parenthesis is missing in upload() {
        this.props.refreshFlatListItem;
    }

Comment: Yes exactly! But I don't think I can do that because there isn't that direct relationship?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give a tree like structure of which component invokes which, do upload and display component have same parent?

Comment: You're right, fixed that up but now getting an error - this.props.refreshFlatListItem is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215605/discussion-between-edison16029-and-james-stirrat).

Answer (score 0):

you can use observer pattern in this case.

I went through this blog in past sharing this with you. I think it will solve your problem.

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-hooks-and-the-observer-pattern-1e4274f0e5f5

you can add this didMount and remove it in unMount of your component.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. This is all completely new to me so I'm going to take some time to go and understand it - will update

Answer (score 0):

Replace your app to be a class component

```
import {Component} from 'react-native'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numberOfUploads: 0
        }
    }

    //Callback funtion
    handleNewUpload() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                numberOfUploads: prevState.numberOfUploads +1
            };
        });
    }

    //Notice that you pass the number of uploads as props
    render(){
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName="Home"
              mode='modal'
              screenOptions={{
                  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
                  cardOverlayEnabled: true
              }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen name="Vault"
                    optons={{headerShown: false }}>
                  {props => <Main {...props} numberOfUploads={this.state.numberOfUploads} />}
                </Stack.Screen>

             <Stack.Screen
                name="Modal"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
             >
             {props => <Modal {...props} handleNewUpload={this.handleNewUpload} />}
             </Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
    }
}
```